# See updates in a DataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, datareader

Is there a way to see the updates done by other users in a table using a DataReader ?

For example : in my DataReader, I am on the 10th row. Another user updates the 11th row. When I do myReader.Read(), I am seeing the old values. Is there a way to see the new values ?

Same question with new rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *might* see them with TransIsolation=DirtyReads, but even then it is uncertain.

The only way to get new data for sure is to re-query

Comment: I've already tried to use a transaction with ReadUncommited as isolation level. It doesn't work...

Comment: It might work when the number of records is larger. It will never be reliable.

Comment: Yes, you're right. With about 100 rows between those records, it works. It means that the datareader handles a cache... Bad news for me...

Comment: @Xavi: the cache is not in the Reader but in the Db and the client API. Pretty fundamental.